# Solving inequality

Tags: inequality

Okay I found this one on a test and I am still struggling to solve this one don't know where to start..here it goes $ 1 \le \frac{(3x^2 -7x+8)}{x^2 +1} \le2 $. How do I find the range of x?

Comment: You run into trouble if the denominator is ever zero. However, $x^2+1 > 0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{3x^2 -7x+8}{x^2 +1} = 3 + \frac{-7x + 5}{x^2 + 1}$$

and thus the inequality is equivalent to

$$-2 \leq \frac{-7x + 5}{x^2 + 1} \leq -1$$

or

$$1 \leq \frac{7x - 5}{x^2 + 1} \leq 2$$

or

$$x^2 + 1 \leq 7x - 5 \leq 2(x^2 + 1)$$

Now this inequality should be (relatively) straight forward to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^2+1>0$ for all $x$. So you do not have problems in the fraction since it is well defined.

As next you have to satisfy both conditions:$\frac{3x^2-7x+8}{x^2+1}\leq 2$ and $\frac{3x^2-7x+8}{x^2+1}\geq 1$.

For the first one you get $3x^2-7x+8\leq 2(x^2+1)$ and the second one $3x^2-7x+8\geq (x^2+1)$.

And so

$3x^2-7x+8\leq 2(x^2+1)\iff x^2-7x+6\leq 0$

$3x^2-7x+8\geq (x^2+1)\iff 2x^2-7x+7\geq 0$.

Now by finding the solution sets of both inequalities and intersecting them you will find your solution set which satisfy your initial relation.